# For R & Java Connection

Tags: java

I write this program

```
import java.util.Vector;
import org.rosuda.Rserve.*;

class rNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    public class RConnection  extends Rengine{
      RConnection c = new RConnection();
      double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles(); 
    }
  }
}
```

this program give error illegal start of expression & ; is expected

Comment: Why do you use inner classes here, what's the reason??

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a public class inside a main function... Declare the class outside. Besides, I don't see the point of your `rNumber` class.

You might do something like this instead :

```
  import java.util.Vector;
  import org.rosuda.Rserve.*;

  public class RConnection  extends Rengine{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      RConnection c = new RConnection();
      double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles(); 
    }
  }
```